# Angular 2 - How to listen to event without a template?

Tags: angular

#### The Problem

Normally, in Angular 2, one would listen to an event via the following syntax:

```
<my-elem (customEvent)="customEventProcessor"></my-elem>
```

But when I use a router, that host - `<my-elem>` - does not exist in any template. Instead, there's a `<router-outlet>`, and my component is loaded upon navigation. Thus, the crux of my problem is, *How can I force my host to listen to my custom event without relying on a template?*

#### Optional Details

Suppose I have some element `list-view`, which is a child of my root component. `list-view` listens for a custom event via the normal syntax:

```
<list-view (customEvent)="customEventProcessor()"></list-view>
```

Just for completeness, the `list-view` component that emits the event also has a predictable structure:

```
<button (click)="onDetailsClick(propertyOfInterest)">Click here</button>
```

The `list-view` sends the event up to the parent via observation.

```
class ListView {

    ...

        public onDetailsClick(property: string): void {

            this.customEvent.next({ value: property });
    
        }

}
```

and that event triggers the `customEventProcessor()` function. So far so good. However, when I use a router to control whether `list-view` is present, I cannot (to my knowledge) insert a command to monitor some event.

I am not sure what the best approach is to handle this case.

Comment: You can set a template for your routes, so that shouldn't change really, probably I misunderstood your problem. Anyway, to *mimic* the HTML way, to emit you can use [`@Output / outputs : []`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Output-var.html) and to listen you can use [`@HostListener / host : {}`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/HostListener-var.html)

Comment: @EricMartinez I don't think your proposal works. As far as I can tell, *custom* events [cannot bubble up](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2296#issuecomment-134377184) to a parent component. If you have an example of how to make a router listen to a custom event, I'm all ears - but I've had no luck here. A demo would be nice.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, I got your issue wrong :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem isn't resolved yet (see [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4452)). Here is one of the possible solutions at this moment (see [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0hrHdO14sHy3LNVWpuiZ?p=preview)):

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
  template: `
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <a [router-link]="['./MyElem1']">MyElem1</a>
    <a [router-link]="['./MyElem2']">MyElem2</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', redirectTo: '/my-elem1' },
  { path: '/my-elem1', name: 'MyElem1', component: MyElem1 },
  { path: '/my-elem2', name: 'MyElem2', component: MyElem2 },
])
export class App {
  message: string = 'Click on the button';

  @ViewChild(MyElem1) myElem1: MyElem1;
  @ViewChild(MyElem2) myElem2: MyElem2;

  constructor(router: Router) {
    let subs = null;
    router.subscribe(() => {
      if (subs) { subs.unsubscribe(); subs = null; }

      if (this.myElem1) {
        subs = this.myElem1.customEvent1.subscribe(m=>this.processCustomEvent(m));
      }
      if (this.myElem2) {
        subs = this.myElem2.customEvent2.subscribe(m=>this.processCustomEvent(m));
      }
    });
  }

  processCustomEvent(message) { this.message = message }
}
```

Comment: So there are two, separate problems: 1) custom events can't bubble to a parent component, and 2) there are no parent-child bindings in a router. The link you provided seems to handle 2) but not 1). Either way, your solution does seem to fix my problem.

Comment: [See also](http://plnkr.co/edit/UGIbAayNvGlwJWZOtPAA?p=preview). Point here is, injecting another router into a child component does not create a new router - it's a singleton. As such, there's little overhead in just using a the childRouter scoped to the child component.

Comment: @Jefftopia, events are supposed to bubble up to parent components.  To handle them, you need to use the carat:  `(^click)="parentFunction()"`  https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-angular-2-custom-events-es5.  but getting the events without the html does seem to be an issue.

Comment: @alexpods just curious, any updates for your answer now that we're out of beta?

Comment: just to help future users, @Jefftopia to your problem 1 - "custom events can't bubble to a parent component" or "force my host to listen to my custom event without relying on a template?" Angular now offer two approaches 1. Parent calls a ViewChild    
"https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child" 2. Parent and children communicate via a service "https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service"